# "CustomFields" error when using MSDEPLOY to export\import Website between servers

Tags: iis, iis-7.5, msdeploy

Source: Server 2012 R2
Destination: Server 2012

This is the command I use to export:

```
C:\Program Files\IIS\Microsoft Web Deploy V3>msdeploy -verb:sync  -source:apphos
tconfig="mywebsite" -dest:package=c:\test.zip,encryptPassword=password -skip:Directory= -skip:File=
```

The following is the error I get in IIS when attempting an import:

> Microsoft.Web.Deployment.DeploymentException: Child object
>   'customFields' cannot be added to object 'logFile'. The 'logFile'
>   provider may not support this deployment.    at
>   Microsoft.Web.Deployment.DeploymentObject.AddChild(DeploymentObject
>   source, Int32 position, DeploymentSyncContext syncContext)    at
>   Microsoft.Web.Deployment.DeploymentSyncContext.HandleAddChild(DeploymentObject
>   destParent, DeploymentObject sourceObject, Int32 position)    at
>   Microsoft.Web.Deployment.DeploymentSyncContext.SyncChildrenOrder(DeploymentObject
>   dest, DeploymentObject source)    at
>   Microsoft.Web.Deployment.DeploymentSyncContext.SyncChildrenOrder(DeploymentObject
>   dest, DeploymentObject source)    at
>   Microsoft.Web.Deployment.DeploymentSyncContext.SyncChildrenNoOrder(DeploymentObject
>   dest, DeploymentObject source)    at
>   Microsoft.Web.Deployment.DeploymentSyncContext.SyncChildrenOrder(DeploymentObject
>   dest, DeploymentObject source)    at
>   Microsoft.Web.Deployment.DeploymentSyncContext.ProcessSync(DeploymentObject
>   destinationObject, DeploymentObject sourceObject)    at
>   Microsoft.Web.Deployment.DeploymentObject.SyncToInternal(DeploymentObject
>   destObject, DeploymentSyncOptions syncOptions, PayloadTable
>   payloadTable, ContentRootTable contentRootTable, Nullable`1
>   syncPassId, String syncSessionId)    at
>   Microsoft.Web.Deployment.DeploymentObject.SyncTo(DeploymentProviderOptions
>   providerOptions, DeploymentBaseOptions baseOptions,
>   DeploymentSyncOptions syncOptions)    at
>   Microsoft.Web.Deployment.UI.InstallProgressWizardPage.OnWorkerDoWork(Object
>   sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)    at
>   System.ComponentModel.BackgroundWorker.WorkerThreadStart(Object
>   argument)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I should have seen this one miles away...

I unzipped the backup file and edited the archive.xml file removing the line with the dredded "customFields". Problem solved.